# Dataframe to plot different charts from groups in columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a `dataframe` that has multiple columns, containing different categories (['A'], ['1','2','3','4'])

```
Index1 Index2    X    Y
A      '1'       1    2
A      '1'       5    3
A      '1'       3    4
A      '2'       3    1
A      '2'       4    1
A      '2'       3    5 
A      '2'       1    2
A      '3'       5    3
A      '3'       3    4
A      '4'       3    1
A      '4'       4    1
A      '4'       3    5
```

I need to loop it so that it brings me four different splatter charts for each pair of indexes (in the future there will be a B index, that's the reason for the multiindex).

My code at the moment brings me one chart for every line (in this example would be 12 of them), if I `break` at the end it brings me only one

I tried `.iterows()` and `.itertuples()` both of them got me the same result (maybe have been using them wrong to)

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Index1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']
Index2 = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','4','4','4']
X = [1,5,3,3,4,3,1,5,3,3,4,3]
Y = [2,3,4,1,1,5,2,3,4,1,1,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(Index1)
df = df.assign(Index2 = Index2,X=X,Y=Y)
df.set_index(['Index1','Index2'])

second_index = 1     
for index in df.itertuples():
    df = df.groupby('Index2').get_group(second_index)
    df.plot.scatter(x = 'X', y = 'Y')
    plt.show()
    break
```

I have a similar code runing on a `dictionary` that works on the same logic and it brings me all the charts that I need.

p.s.: that's not the real code just the general idea, and I might have made some mistakes

Comment: What exactly is the question here? What is the purpose of the loop? Not providing a [mcve] here means essentially that you ask other people to do all the work for you. While creating such a [mcve] by yourself would probably even allow you to solve the issue alone without the need to ask a question here - and in case it doesn't you have the [mcve] to post here.

Comment: I'm sorry that I made it to complicated, I was just trying to explain as best as possible, I edited the question to better replicate the situation, as I said in the post, the problem is that when I run my code instead of the code ploting 1 chart per pair of index it's ploting the same chart for each row in the dataframe

Comment: Note that you do not have a `Multiindex` here. What you call `Index` is a normal column.

Comment: I know, I added it after, but it isn't working for some reason (in the original code is and I have no idea why) `df.set_index(['Index1','Index2'])` I mean...

Comment: Just keep it like this. An index should somehow index your data, which wouldn't be the case if there are several identical indices for different rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what the loop is doing, but if a loop variable is not used anywhere inside the loop it's a good sign that the loop is not even needed.

Here it seems you want to plot each group, hence

```
df.groupby("Index2").plot(x="X", y="Y", kind="scatter")
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Index1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']
Index2 = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','2','3','3','4','4','4']
X = [1,5,3,3,4,3,1,5,3,3,4,3]
Y = [2,3,4,1,1,5,2,3,4,1,1,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(Index1)
df = df.assign(Index2 = Index2,X=X,Y=Y)

df.groupby("Index2").plot(x="X", y="Y", kind="scatter")

plt.show()
```

However, if you really *want* to loop for whatever reason, you could loop over the `groupby`:

```
for (n, group) in df.groupby("Index2"):
    group.plot.scatter(x="X", y="Y")
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I meant, I'm sorry about my question being off the regulations! I'm new to all this, but thank you! It was so simple in the end, I spent a few hours on this...